# Waypoints: do something if offset is less than something

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to toggle a navbar class if the body offset is less than -20px using Waypoints plugin.

The code below doesn't work because the offset values is undefined.

Is there any way to retrieve the body offset value using Waypoints?

```
$("body").waypoint(function() {
    if (offset > -20px) {
      $(".navbar-toggle").on('click', function() {
          $(".navbar").toggleClass("navbar-default navbar-inverse");
      });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`.offset()` returns an object containing the properties `top` and `left`.

```
$("body").waypoint(function() {
    var offsetTop = $('body').offset().top; // top offSet
    var offsetLeft = $('body').offset().left; // left offSet
    if (offsetTop > -20) { // or offsetLeft > -20 with out `px`
      $(".navbar-toggle").on('click', function() {
          $(".navbar").toggleClass("navbar-default navbar-inverse");
      });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, ozil. However, I cannot make it work. It always gives my offsetTop equal to '0'. I tried to check it with: $("body").waypoint(function() {
    var offsetTop = $('body').offset().top;
    if (offsetTop < -20) {
      console.log(offsetTop);
    }
}); but it doesn't show no data.

Comment: @  Deka87 if it gives `0` then `if (offsetTop < -20) ` statement  will not execute.